# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str for larger data

Tags: python

This code will work when the id is for a user with less badges(e.g inputting the value 2 for the player id). However, it will not work for players with more badges (e.g player id 261) and will show the error: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" In line 37

```
import requests
import json
import urllib, json
import time

proxies = {"http": "http://176.9.75.42:3128",
           "http": "http://88.198.50.103:8080"}


def jprint(obj):
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print(text)


user_id = input("What is the user ID: ")
URL = f"https://badges.roblox.com/v1/users/{user_id}/badges"
data = []
payload = {"limit": 100, "sortOrder": "Asc"}
resp = requests.get(URL, params=payload)
resp.json()
blob = resp.json()
data.extend(blob["data"])
cursor = blob["nextPageCursor"]

while cursor is not None:
    if cursor is None:
        break
    print("Getting ids")
    time.sleep(0)
    payload.update({"cursor": cursor})
    resp = requests.get(URL, params=payload, proxies=proxies)
    blob = resp.json()
    data.extend(blob["data"])
    cursor = blob["nextPageCursor"]
    data.append([cursor])

id_list = [each['id'] for each in data]
print(id_list)
```

Comment: Have you taken the basic step of printing out the values you get to see where you're going wrong?  You didn't even tell us which line gets the error.  `data` is a strange mix of `blob['data']` and `[blob['nextPageCursor']]`.  Are you sure that's what you intended?

Comment: @TimRoberts In line 37 I get this error I believe everything else is fine and what I intended

Comment: Print out your data list before you try to extract the id_list. You will find that your data list does not just hold dicts. Somewhere in there you have a list instead of a dict. That's why you're seeing the error you mention. Your each['id'] expects that each will be a dict. But one of your each'es is a list, and thus causes the error. It's probably either an append/extend issue. Maybe "data.append([cursor])" should not have cursor in the square brackets? That's a hunch without looking deeper into your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your code running and looked more deeply into it.

Your issues is that the line:

```
cursor = blob["nextPageCursor"]
```

is setting cursor to a string. You then add that to the data list, as a list. But later on, you expect each item in data to be a dict, because you are calling:

```
id_list = [each['id'] for each in data]
```

But the entry into the data list that you added for cursor is a list, not a dict, and has no 'id' key.  You could stub it easily enough to get it running by changing:

```
data.append([cursor])
```

to something like:

```
data.append({'cursor': cursor, 'id': 0})
```

or you could change:

```
id_list = [each['id'] for each in data]
```

to:

```
id_list = [each.get('id') for each in data if isinstance(each, dict)]
```

Or you can rework your logic around grabbing/storing cursor to make a more robust solution.